# MySQL using a special query for unique data

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query that displays about 10 unique items from about 5,000 records..

```
SELECT DISTINCT (stockSymbol) AS myStock FROM 'USDJPY' ORDER BY myStock DESC

1865
1765
1632
etc..
```

my question is how can I make just one query that would DISTINCT but also (COUNT) how many records '1865' have and '1765' etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the `stockSymbol` and then use the `count()` function on each group

```
SELECT stockSymbol,
       count(*) as stockCount
FROM USDJPY
group by stockSymbol
ORDER BY stockCount DESC
```

Comment: yeah trying to know if its possible to have the same distinct and count in one query..

Comment: @XK8ER `GROUP BY stockSymbol` effectively makes a distinct set. If this doesn't give you the result you expect, you need to post a sample output set above, along with a more complete sample input rowset.